# IOS Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

I tried to put AFNetworking 2.0 framework by usual drag and drop in iOS. Then when I execute the application it says the below errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TableViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TableViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.
I tried to use cocoapods but for some reason I couldn't install cocoapods in my machine.

Comment: it looks like you are using the Mac framework.  iOS one is compiled with arm symbols

Comment: @jeef...AFNetworking 2.0 doesnt have separate frameworks.

Comment: Well then thats your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I spent a couple of hours fighting with this exact same issue, going through all the Google hits I could find. Building for the device was working, but building for the simulator was not.

Here are the steps that finally solved the issue for me:

1. Clear the XCode caches:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
   ```
2. Clear the CocoaPods caches and reinstall the dependencies:

   ```
   rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
   rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
   pod update
   ```
3. Finally go to the "Pods" project and set the `Build Active Architectures Only` to `No` also for the "Debug" configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I used xCode 6.1.1, download and add to project updated AFNetworking and had the same problem, but with old version AFNetworking worked good. 
Check this two ways, worked for me: 
1) update xCode

2) download old version AFNetworking

Comment: I can only find new version in github

Answer (score 0):

This kind of weird stuff started to happen after Xcode 11.4.**1** update. Any library, framework that you previously had, and didn't have the symbols to be compiled to iOS simulator(x86_64) can show these errors... 
One solution is to recompile the framework in your machine adding the all architectures needed. I haven't recompiled AFNetworking lately, so I cannot give you a step by step on that... But probably in AFNetworking repo, they should have a makefile or configure script to that kind of thing. 
Good luck!